# configur mecury in xampp to send mail

Tags: localhost, xampp, sendmail

I am debugging a mail feature, and need Mercury to send mail from xampp, how do i do that?
Are there alternatives?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer (a work around) some time. I didn't want to tamper with mecury settings, as i may need to send mail within localhost later, so i used this work around.

what i did was to download php mailer and use the smtp class. I used google smtp setting ie. smtp.google.com, and my google username and password. so when ever i want to send mail from localhost, phpmailer simple uses google to send the mail instead.

if you need more help, please let me know